# How to access a particular value from mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php script that selects everything from invoiceNo where invoiceNo is distinct.

```
<?php

require 'init.php';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` WHERE invoiceNo IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items ) GROUP BY invoiceNo;';
$res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$result = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($result, [
        'custInfo'    => $row[0],
        'invoiceNo'   => $row[1],
        'barcode'     => $row[2],
        'description' => $row[3],
        'weight'      => $row[4],
        'rate'        => $row[5],
        'makingAmt'   => $row[6],
        'net_rate'    => $row[7],
        'itemTotal'   => $row[8],
        'vat'         => $row[9],
        'sum_total'   => $row[10],
        'bill_type'   => $row[11],
        'date'        => $row[12],
        'advance'     => $row[13],
        'balance'     => $row[14],
    ]);
}
echo json_encode(['result' => $result]);
mysqli_close($con);
```

[image]

Right now this script gives me the first value from sum_total i.e it gives me the first row from my database how can I get the last row.I am new to programming any suggestions or help is appreciated.Thanks :)

Comment: why don't you use sorting `DESC`?

Comment: @AjayMakwana can you give an example.Thanks :)

Comment: i think you want max sum_total from the unique invoice right ?
do you want all invoice with that or only sort by desc sum_total

Comment: @rahul yes exactly.Can you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * From (
SELECT t.*, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM selected_items t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r order by rank DESC
) si GROUP BY si.invoiceNo;
```

This query solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` WHERE invoiceNo IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items ) ORDER BY `sum_total` DESC";
$query ="SELECT max( `sum_total` ) FROM selected_items";
```

Where `column_name` can be vary.

Comment: This gives the same result I still get the first row

Comment: @AjayMakwana your second query will give only one record

Comment: you want all the record and the first record should with maximum total?
Then try removing `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think this is you want, may it help

```
$query ="SELECT max( `sum_total` ) FROM `selected_items` GROUP BY invoiceNo;";
```

Comment: else you can modify it on your requirement or tell me what exactly you want

Comment: Rahul but also want all the values from that row.Can't I just get the last row for that particular invoice.Thanks :)

Comment: yeah sure just add the selected values by comma after max('sum_total'), example_field from .....

Comment: ya i tried that but it still gets the first row I have no idea why?

Comment: in your db there is no unique field to identify the last inserted record its same values for all the fields even the date except sum_total, can you make your date differ so we can try by fetching record by last updated date time

Comment: Yes that would be cool but it is date and time so how would we do that?

Comment: by setting date order by to desc in your inner query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98308/discussion-between-anup-and-rahul).

Comment: can you give a example

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get only last record use limit.

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` GROUP BY invoiceNo ORDER BY `sum_total` DESC limit 1;
```

If you need to get highest to lowest sum_total record try the below code,

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM `selected_items` where `sum_total` = (SELECT max( `sum_total` ) FROM `selected_items` GROUP BY invoiceNo) GROUP BY invoiceNo ORDER BY `sum_total` DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks Arun I tried both your solutions the first one still gives me the first row.And the 2nd one gives an error saying 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: I missed to add `sum_total` for order by  in 2nd query. Now edited it. Ok. I need to know one thing clearly, Do u want all records with unique invoiceNo or Final record only?

Comment: The second one gives an error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: instead of ORDER BY `sum_total` DESC use ORDER BY GREATEST(`sum_total`) in 1st query and let me know.

Comment: I tried this SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` GROUP BY invoiceNo ORDER BY GREATEST (sum_total) DESC limit 1; it gave an error #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'GREATEST'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98342/discussion-between-arun-and-anup).